# mysql connection terminates when i logoff from the remote server

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh

I had  written a script that connects to the local mysql server every 6 seconds and checks if there is any data in the table .if there is data it runs some php commands and then deletes that data from the table.  I logged into my remote server(Shared hosting) through ssh and then copied the script and executed it using command "nohup ./script.sh 0<&- &>alert.log &" so that it runs in background and  writes all the output to alert.log file. my problem is that when i log in to the server through SSH and execute the script it runs perfectly , but when i log out from server its not running . when i check the alert.log file after it is showing error "cannot connect to local mysql server". any solutions ??

this is the code

```
while true
      do


    res=($(mysql -u root -p123456 --skip-column-names -Dtest -e "select id from temptab"))

        if [[ "$res" > 0 ]];then
        del=`mysql -u root -p123456  -Dtest -e "delete from temptab;" `

        now="$(date +'%d/%m/%Y:%H.%M.%S')"

        for ((i=0; i < ${#res[@]}; i++))
        do
        php -n /var/lib/mysql/trigger.php ${res[$i]}
        echo "[$now]:Trigger called with videoid ${res[$i]}" 

        done

        fi

    sleep 6
done
```

and this is the sample output
cat nohup.out
    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.20
    Content-type: text/html

```
{"multicast_id":8864856209398719411,"success":2,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1385797766832904%4f0c6467f9fd7ecd"},{"error":"InvalidRegistration"},{"message_id":"0:1385797766832901%4f0c6467f9fd7ecd"}]}81Inserted police info
[30/11/2013:00.49.26]:Trigger called with videoid 65
/etc/bashrc: line 14: whoami: command not found
/etc/bashrc: line 20: grep: command not found
/etc/bashrc: line 59: dircolors: command not found
./alert.sh: line 15: php: command not found
[30/11/2013:07.50.27]:Trigger called with videoid 70
./alert.sh: line 15: /ramdisk/php/54/bin/php54: No such file or directory
[30/11/2013:09.09.52]:Trigger called with videoid 71
```

Answer (score 2):

`screen` is what you need. There are plenty of tutorials on [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux%20screen&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t) on screen usage.

Comment: yea i tried screen also..... in my script im executing a php command .... when i login to the server through ssh  the php command is executing but when i get disconnect from server ... the php command is not getting excuted at all...... when i saw the alert.log file it is showing error as " php: command not found  " ..... i think my shell is losing all its resources when i get disconnected

Comment: Ssh to the server. Start sceen. Run your php code. Detach screen. Logout from ssh session.  Screen will continue to run on the remote server which in turn will run php code. Regarding command not found, provide more information.

Comment: ok this is my script  --->>   
 while true
do


res=($(mysql -u root -p123456 --skip-column-names -Dtest -e "select id from temptab"))

if [[ "$res" > 0 ]];then
del=`mysql -u root -p123456  -Dtest -e "delete from temptab;" `

now="$(date +'%d/%m/%Y:%H.%M.%S')"

for ((i=0; i < ${#res[@]}; i++))
do
php -n /var/lib/mysql/trigger.php ${res[$i]}
echo "[$now]:Trigger called with videoid ${res[$i]}" 

done

fi

sleep 6
done

Comment: and this is sample-output
cat nohup.out
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.20
Content-type: text/html

{"multicast_id":8864856209398719411,"success":2,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1385797766832904%4f0c6467f9fd7ecd"},]}81Inserted police info
[30/11/2013:00.49.26]:Trigger called with videoid 65
./alert.sh: line 15: php: command not found
[30/11/2013:07.50.27]:Trigger called with videoid 70
./alert.sh: line 15: /ramdisk/php/54/bin/php54: No such file or directory
[30/11/2013:09.09.52]:Trigger called with videoid 7

Comment: update your code and output in question. Its just not possible to understand it in comments.

Comment: i can run the script in background it works as long as i am in the ssh session but as soon as i log out of the ssh session ... my script is showing those errors

Comment: You said you tried screen but I am not sure how exactly you are running screen. I have mentioned a basic flow of using screen in one my comments above. If you follow this sequence, I don't see a reason why you are facing this issue. In other words, Could you provide exact steps that you follow while using screen. I have used screen all my life and I am confident that screen will resolve this issue.

Comment: oh first i logged in using ssh as "ssh user@domain.com "   then i navigated through the path to my script as" cd /path/to my.script"    then i entered  screen command as " screen " then i entered command to run my script as " nohup ./script.sh 0<&- &>alert.log & " then i detached the screen by pressing ctrl+a followed by d ... i confirmed whether it is detached by command " screen -ls" which showed that it is detached. After that i logged off by typing "exit" ...........

Comment: i inserted data into tables using phpmyadmin from browser ... when i loged into ssh again to check the alert.log file .... it is showing error as php: command not found ..... i also gave the full path to the php command ............but it is not working at all....... is it something related to sessions or permissions..??

Comment: yea i have also tried that   ......   it is also not working.... actually my site is on  sharedhsoting... so im not the root user...... does that effect it in anyway....??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to move your code into a crontab even that will run every X minutes (5 minutes, or anything else you like) rather than have your user run it during a live session.

Just place the PHP script inside a call to cron, login, and run `crontab -e` then add:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/username/phpscript.php
```

Comment: yea but the minimum time that can be set in cron tab is 1 min..... but i want the script to be excuted every 6th second to check for updates in database

Comment: If it were perl I would say "fork", ``forking`` allows processes to run detached from their parents, I don't know the equivalent in php

Comment: can u suggest me how to add the command "nohup ./script.sh 0<&- &>alert.log &" to the cron job

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run your script like:

```
/path/to/script.sh </dev/null &>/home/yourname/alert.log &

disown
```

I

Answer (score -1):

finally i got the solution .... i was using /usr/bin/php to call my php files  but .....when i edited it to /usr/bin/php.orig it started working........... but what is that php.orig...??  @all thanks